# What is the big o notation of common cpython string operations

Tags: python

I am trying to check what is the time/space complexity of common python string operations like:

- len
- join
- append
- insert to the middle of a string

the complexity obviously depends on the implementation, for example:

1. len can cost either O(1) or O(n) depends if the string
   implementation holds another parameter to update it every time the
   lengh changes or not.
2. append can be implemented by O(1) by taking the last pointer that
   points to null and pointing it to the start of the next string, or
   O(n) if creating a new array and copying the data.
3. Inserting to the middle of a string can be done like I suggested in 2, just pointing the pointers correctly thus costing O(1) instead of O(n).

I couldn't find anything in the official documentation regarding the cost of such operations. The best I found was https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt but it didn't cover strings.

Comment: python strings don't have an append (or insert)method- lists do (but have no join method)

Comment: yes I understand, but the idea is to find the actual costs of operations in python not function-specific, I just couldn't find any place with the actual time and space notations

Comment: strings are immuteable. append and insert into middle of string are impossible. you create new strings if you "append" using + or slice to remove from the middle

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As always, look at the source.

- [Retrieving a string's length is O(1)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b0d4949f1fb04f83691e10a5453d1e10e4598bb9/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L123-L124).
- [`join`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b0d4949f1fb04f83691e10a5453d1e10e4598bb9/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L10018) is more complex and has quite some optimizations in place.
- [Concatenation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b0d4949f1fb04f83691e10a5453d1e10e4598bb9/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L11349) is an allocation and two string copy operations.

Comment: So, there is no simple source where I can find all the time and space complexity?
Just have to go over all the implementations of string functions in the standard library?
BTW, thanks for the link to the implementation, I actually wasn't able to find it.